# Does craco override existing config settings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, craco

When using craco, I wonder if the existing configuration file is overwritten or added to the existing options?

```
//craco.config.ts

module.exports = {
    babel: {
      presets: ["@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"]
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will override.
For example, let's say you have a CRA project with the following default configuration:
// default configuration

```
module.exports = {
  react: {
    version: '16.13'
  }
};
```

If you use CRACO to override the default configuration with the following configuration:

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  react: {
    version: '16.9'
  }
};
```

Then the default configuration will be replaced with the new configuration that you provided. The final configuration for the project will be:

```
// final configuration
module.exports = {
  react: {
    version: '16.9'
  }
};
```